# Previous home owner had hole drilled for shower drain through the metal web joist in the floor. Is this structurally ok?

Tags: plumbing, flooring, subfloor, support, truss

It was approved by the town inspector, but maybe they missed it. I would like to know if this is ok structurally.

[image]

Comment: That part of the structure is in compression, not tension.  That helps.

Comment: Was it a good job... no.  Is it funny that the only place in the world they could output the plumbing was in the 4 inch area that had the joist... yes.  Is there anything even mildly catastrophic that will come from this... doubt it.

Comment: That would be the place I would have drilled as there is support on both sides of the hole. There should have been added pico nails added to the plate on the far side at least 4 if not 6 on each side of the hole to hold the plate in place. If you notice any splices they are usually in this location for strength not in the middle of a span.

Comment: Looks like plywood flooring, could even be 3/4". Wouldn't this provide a lot of extra support to the truss? A builder I know says plumbers and HVAC installers are famous for cutting structural elements, and everybody yells at them about it, but there is so much of a safety factor that the structure can handle it. A shower is not going to have a large amount of extra weight concentrated on that one spot. If support is added I would use screws (construction adhesive?) to avoid jarring something loose above. If a 2x4 would interfere, then use a 2x2 or angle steel.

Comment: I agree with Jim. A floor system is just that--a system. The subfloor makes up for any compression strength lost to the hole. I'd follow Trevor's advice and lay in some rails along the hole. That said, the builder and plumber should've been communicating when the floor trusses were set. That never should've happened.

Comment: @JimStewart, good points, though by shower, it would depend if it's a stand alone shower or a bathtub shower. A bathtub full of water is a large load I would not want atop that join in MY house.

Answer (score 1):

Um.. NO. That is a HUGE hole in the width of that strut. and those nail plates are not strong enough to handle compression like that.

They should have added a couple of 2x4s  (Narrow side up) , nailed frequently to the top strut, across and on either side of that join, preferably to the next web, to replace the material lost.

They should also have fired the plumber or the architect...

It does look like you can add the 2x4s yourself fairly easily, though swinging the hammer on the rear side may be a challenge.

Comment: I generally agree, except that any repairs to an engineered truss should really have the blessing of an engineer. Were it my home, I'd sister (with construction adhesive and screws) lumber as you describe and forget about it.

Comment: Also, the general contractor was responsible for coordinating framing and plumbing, and should've directed the framing crew to shift a truss. The plumber had no choice by the time his turn was up.

Comment: Not sure I agree @Isherwood, the plumber had the choice of saying.. I can't run the pipe there unless you bolster that joist. Whether he did, and was told to look the other way, and chose to do so, is another thing. Either way, that install should NOT have happened a is.